# Start the API call as soon as record inserted in Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, background-task

I have a requirement, if a record inserted in local DB(Sqlite) as soon as possible app triggers API call to send offline record to server. I don't want to use **Timer** and **Alarm service** because those will run continuously in background even there is no offline records in local DB. Any other alternative solutions?

Note: Target SDK level is Andorid 8 version.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood your task (in general) - is how to invoke some function (some **sendNewRecord()** for instance) when new row(s) were inserted in some Sqlite table.

I suppose there are 3 alternative ways to implement such a task in Sqlite:

1. **To invoke your function at the same place in code where you put your insert-new-data code**. I think that's the most obvious and the simplest choice. I hope in your app there is only one place where you do it (Repository pattern or its analogue).
2. **To put some observer(callback function) to your table and process changes in table**. That more complicated task, and as far as I know you'll get this callback after every change in your table and it would be another task to identify what rows in your table were changed. Using modern Room framework and LiveData as a query result, you can observe changes in the table in more strait-forward way, but then nevertheless you have to detect inserted rows.
3. **To use some scheduling mechanism for syncing (Executor, Timer and so on)**. You've wrote that it's not your case.

I would recommend you to choose **first way**. At least I don't see its disadvantages.